# Properties on Observable aren't being found when bound to in template

Tags: html, angular, typescript, rxjs, ngxs

I'm calling data from an NGXS state which when I `console.log()` shows is present in the shape of the interface used to describe it.  There's an `items` property which is an array of 3 objects which I want to iterate over in my template.  However when I target the `items` property I get an error in vsCode telling me the property doesn't exist on that type and nothing renders on the screen.

My state model looks like this

```
export interface CattegoryIndexItem{
    cattegory: string;
    products: ProductIndexListItem[];
}

export interface ProductIndexListModel{ items: CattegoryIndexItem[]; }
```

my component looks like this

```
export class ProductPageComponent implements OnInit {

  @Select() productIndexState$: Observable<ProductIndexListModel>;

  constructor(private store: Store) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.store.dispatch(new GetProductIndexList());

  }

  showData(){
    this.productIndexState$.subscribe(res => console.log(res));
  }

}
```

inside my template

```
<article *ngFor="let item of productIndexState$.items | async">
    <p>{{item.cattegory}}</p>
</article>

<button (click)="showData()">click</button>
```

When the page loads I get this error

> error TS2339: Property 'items' does not exist on type 'Observable'.

I've never had this problem working with observables, is there something NGXS does that makes us need to access it differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a glitch in the template syntax - can't call `.items` on the Observable itself, you want to call it on the object emitted by that `Observable`.

So you need to pipe the `Observable` via `async` first e.g.

```
<ng-container *ngIf="productIndexState$ | async as productIndexState">
    <article *ngFor="let item of productIndexState.items">
        <p>{{item.cattegory}}</p>
    </article>

    <button (click)="showData()">click</button>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: SPLENDID!!! THIS WORKS!!! now what makes this occur and why don't any of the tutorials I see ever need to do these types of things for it all to work out the box?

Comment: Ha I can't answer that, but glad it is working now!
I like this `ng-container` pattern for this sort of thing - makes it clear (to me at least) that I'm subscribing to the observable, and everything in the `ng-container` is in the context of the value emitted.

Answer (score 1):

Glad that the given answer already helps.

I'd like to answer your comment here just to add to that answer.

You asked: *now what makes this occur?*

Now whats happening is this:

Your method *showData()* calls subscribe on the observable itself and unwraps it. This should have the structure of your interface. This interface then has the items property.

Your async pipe in your template

```
<article *ngFor="let item of productIndexState$.items | async">
    <p>{{item.cattegory}}</p>
</article>
```

on the other site does not target the observable itself, but the items property. This does not exist here yet and also it not a valid observable which async could handle.

The [async pipe of Angular](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe) works similar to the subscribe within showData(). It takes whatever is wrapped inside an observable and makes it available for processing.

What @Garth Mason did in his answer was calling async on the observable first to "unwrap" it and using the alias *as* to give it a proper name (without the $). The unwrapped object contains the items you are looking for which now can be iterated over via ngfor.

His code again for better reference:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="productIndexState$ | async as productIndexState">
    <article *ngFor="let item of productIndexState.items">
        <p>{{item.cattegory}}</p>
    </article>

    <button (click)="showData()">click</button>
</ng-container>
```

Just an additional comment on the ng-container wrapping your  tag. Angular only allows a [single directive](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#one-structural-directive-per-host-element) like ngFor or ngIf on a tag. Therefor, whenever you need to do two "Angular process steps" within your template, you need something to do the first step ([the ng-container here](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#one-structural-directive-per-host-element)) and then your actual tags () which does the second step. The ng-container does not have a markup and it therefor not visible in your HTML. This is why it's perfect to wrap such processing steps ;-)

Comment: Yep, I use `ng-container` quite a bit, either because the single structural directive rule you referred to, or because sometimes its more readable than trying to inline multiple conditions against a single `ngIf` or `ngFor`